# React/nextjs fetch data on a button click, but the button is in a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a function in the that fetches the weather data for current location when button is clicked. I want to get this data from the Location component to the pages/index.tsx where I have another components that displays that data.

This is my component structure:

```
App
  --Layout
    --Header
      --Location (here i fetch the data on click)
    --Home (state)
      --Display 1
        --SubDisplay 1
      --Display 2
```

Do I have to pass the data through all the components to the index page? It would be:

1. UP from Location to Header
2. UP from Header to Layout
3. DOWN from Layout to Index page
4. DOWN from Index page to another components

Is this the best way to handle this?

Comment: [this classic page](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) should show you how to do this. Note that you can use the React context API to avoid having to pass data down multiple levels, if you want to (but you probably shouldn't unless there are many levels to pass it down where it won't be being used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to React's nature regarding data flow, you can only pass `props` down from parent component to its children, this is known as one-way data binding or unidirectional data flow. Based on the structure of your components, to achieve what you want to do you would need to use `Context` API or something like `redux` to centralize your data in one place (or just lifting the states up). However you can try this "workaround" so you don't need to modify your project's structure:

Since your state is in the index/home page, you could define a function in this component that will receive as parameter the data fetched in `Location` component and set the state with this data, of course you'd need to pass this function via `props` to `Layout` component so it can pass it to `Header` and `Header` to `Location` (prop drilling), example:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const handleData = (data) => {
    setData(data);
  }

  return (
    <Layout handleData={handleData}>
      The rest of your components...
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Then like I said, pass that function this way: Layout - Header - Location.

In `Location`:

```
const Location = ({ handleData }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    // Fetch your data on click event and pass it as parameter to handleData function

    handleData(fetchedData);
  }

  // The rest of your component...
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested solutions based on more complexity

1. [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)
2. [React context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
3. [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

---

**Lifting state up (Easier than other) sample code**

1. Define shipping function and weatherData as a state in Layout Component,  then send *shippingFunction* into Header component then Location component as prop

```js
const [weatherData,setWeatherData]=useState();
const shippingFunction = function(data) { setWeatherData(data);}
```

2. Location Component

   - Call **props.shippingFunction** in Layout component when weather
     data was fetched, then send weather data into
     **props.shippingFunction** as parameter. Now you have weather data
     in Layout component
3. Layout Component

   - At this moment you have filled **weatherData** and you can pass it as **prop** into any component you want

---